# CSS? Page header/colours show up in safari but not in firefox or chrome

Tags: css

I have been trying to sort this issue for over a week with no joy. I think it must be a css issue but just can't fathom out what I have got wrong.  I'm self-taught so would be grateful for any help.

My website is www.infantsleepresources.com

The CSS is [here](http://roycie.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/style.css)

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind making a [Short, Self-Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) so we can sort out the particular issue?

Comment: Sorry,thanks for the link, will make it more succinct next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websafe image file types are: `jpg`, `gif`, `png`. You should not use `tif`.

Change the image to one of the others, and you should find it works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much - it work's a treat.  I've wasted so much time on this and am extremely grateful for your help.